# Center control group in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, footer

I have a control group in jQuery Mobile that is part of the footer:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="toomanynotes-back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="toomanynotes-play" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="toomanynotes-next" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
</div>
```

It appears alright, but it is always as far left in the footer as it can go. I found [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-horizontally-center-a-set-of-grouped-buttons) forum post, but it didn't work for me. How can I center the control group (horizontally) in a footer?

Comment: identical question and solution for JQM 1.1.1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503603/how-do-i-center-a-horizontal-control-group-in-the-footer-changed-in-jqm-1-1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that some other CSS properties worked:

```
#playdiv {
    font-size:1.0em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    left:50%
}
```

Comment: Good that it worked for you, b/c doesn't seem like this is the correct approach. "left:50%" aligns the left edge of the div at the center of the screen, doesn't center the div horizontally. A hardcoded value for the "left" doesn't work either, if you resize the browser, the controlgroup doesn't look center aligned anymore.

Comment: @SamikR: Thanks for the info. I don't have much experience
 in JQ and JS, so please tell me if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 just put this code on your CSS:

```
.ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup,
.ui-field-contain fieldset.ui-controlgroup {
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I'm not working in the project anymore, but I might try this out.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have changed in jqm 1.1.1.  text-align:center; worked, but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I've had to do in 1.2.0 is to centre it using
text-align: center

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted about two hours trying to centre buttons by modifying the CSS. I would highly recommend using a layout grid instead.

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" data-theme="c">Cancel</button></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b">Submit</button></div>     
</fieldset>
```

Source: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html