# How do I center a horizontal control group in the footer - changed in jqm 1.1.1?

Tags: jquery-mobile, center, footer

This used to work to center the controlgroup in 1.1.0, but now it seems like it doesn't in 1.1.1.

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" style="text-align:center;">
   <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
      <a href="foo" data-role="button">link1</a>
      <a href="boo" data-role="button">link2</a>
   </div>
   <div class="copy">&copy; 2012 bigco</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've had to change my controlgroups to buttons with content grids for the time being until they work the bugs out of jQM 1.1.1 
See here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html

Answer (score 11):

Probably **align="center"** attribute of **data-role="controlgroup"** div could be suitable for that.

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" align="center">
   <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
      <a href="foo" data-role="button">link1</a>
      <a href="boo" data-role="button">link2</a>
   </div>
   <div class="copy">&copy; 2012 bigco</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sGFTy/1/

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution on this site:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-horizontally-center-a-set-of-grouped-buttons

The CSS:

```
#navgroup {text-align:center;}
#navgroup div {display:inline-block;}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="navgroup">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
      <a href="index.htm" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="active menu">Menu</a>
      <a href="specials.htm" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="specials">Specials</a>
      <a href="howitworks.htm" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" class="howitworks">FAQ</a>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" data-rel="external" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true"  class="feedback">Facebook</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue still persists if using
     $("selector").show();
to display element since it applies 'display:block'.

Instead of using .show(), now use 
   $("selector").css('display', 'inline-block');

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm on JQM 1.2 and this works for me...

CSS

```
.center-controlgroup { text-align: center; }
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="center-controlgroup">...</div>
```